# Change dropdown lists dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to make a small voting system for school.

I have 2 dropdown lists. You have 10 points to vote with. If the person selects 9 at the first dropdown list the second dropdownlist shows only the number 1. The other way around it does the same.

My code for this code:

```
        protected void ddLuuk_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

//dd means dropdownlist.

        ddGabriel.Items.Clear();
        var value = ddLuuk.SelectedValue;
        if (value == "10")
        {
            ddGabriel.Items.Add("0");
        }
        else if (value == "9")
        {
            ddGabriel.Items.Add("1");
        }
        else if (value == "8")
        {
            ddGabriel.Items.Add("1");
            ddGabriel.Items.Add("2");
        }

// etc etc.
```

Now my problem with this code: Let's say I have to increase the number to 100. We shouldn't make 100 of those else if constructions.

My question is: How can I make this code much more cleaner and make it work with 100 numbers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint - instead of dealing with strings, you can parse (int.Parse) value and deal with numbers. that should make it trivial

Comment: I think I have to use some sort of for loop for this?

Comment: Yes, you need to use a loop.  Look at the incoming value.  Subtract it from 100 to get a difference value.  Add the difference value to the second drop-down, then increment the incoming value.  Loop while the incoming value is less than 100.  Earn an A+.

Comment: just use linq. You can create a datasource automatically via `IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);` if the value of the first dropdown is 8 the use this: `IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10 - <value of first dropdown>);`

Comment: @Hoffma Yeah that's it I think I'm trying to figure out the for loop now.

Comment: Linq is too much for a student project like this.  When you're trying to figure out what kind of loop to use, you won't benefit from a crash course in IEnumerable.

Comment: @SebastianSchulz I could use it. But It's something I don't understand so I'd prefer not using it. A for loop is the best to use I think.

Comment: @Hoffma Do you know how I could make this for loop?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this.  I often prefer Do-While loops like the one I previously described, but this is better with a simple for loop.  I'll post an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
    private int totalPoints = 100;
    protected void ddLuuk_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddGabriel.Items.Clear();
        var value = ddLuuk.SelectedValue;

        int pointsToGive = totalPoints - Convert.ToInt32(value);

        for (int i = 0; i < pointsToGive ; i++)
        {
            ddGabriel.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Basically we are going to calculate the difference of the points you gave someone and the total points you can give someone. That difference is used to add in an loop new elements.

I guess usually though Javascript would be more fitting.

Comment: This gives an error :  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'

Comment: Now I have this error: Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string.

Comment: Value is an string, needs to be converted to an Int. I edited the answer. It is important though if this is an homework assignment that you try an bit yourself (troubleshooting these errors).

Comment: This worked. Yes I'm aware of that. It's not really an homework assignment, it's more a own project. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: I was about to suggest the same, only without defining totalPoints:

var value = ddLuuk.SelectedValue; //Assuming values of 1 - 100 available here.
var difference = 100 - value;
for (i = 1; i <= difference; i++)
{
ddGabriel.Items.Add(i.ToString());
}

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, all results are '10 - ValueOfDropDown'.

Generalizing, we could say that 10 is the maximum dropdown value. So, putting it in a variable i would become 'MaxValue - ValueOfDropDown'

The only thing you should be aware of is that you need to parse the dropdown value in order to make it a number, for this use 'int.Parse(value)'

Answer (score 0):

Since this is probably homework, I'll help you by giving a clue: you will need a for loop

Comment: Yeah I understand that. I'm trying to find out what sort of for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
        ddGabriel.Items.Clear();
        var value = (int)ddLuuk.SelectedValue;
        if (value == 10)
        {
            Enumerable.Range(0, 1).ToList().ForEach(i => ddGabriel.Items.Add(i.ToString()));
        }
        else if (value < 10)
        {
            Enumerable.Range(1, 10 - value).ToList().ForEach(i => ddGabriel.Items.Add(i.ToString()));
        }
```

Comment: I get a error while using this : Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'.

Comment: you can use `Convert.ToInt32(ddLuuk.SelectedValue)` instead of `(int)ddLuuk.SelectedValue`

Comment: Yeah, It came to my mind later. But I'll stick with a for loop instead of linq since I don't understand linq at all. Thanks anyway for your help!